# ArgumentError in StaticPages#manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with item creation. I have next error:

```
ArgumentError in StaticPages#manager

Showing /home/verevkinra/apps/yurta24/app/views/items/_new.html.erb where line #2 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Extracted source (around line #2):
<h1>Items manage</h1>
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :variable1 %>
   <%= f.text_field :variable2 %>
   <%= f.text_field :variable3 %>
   <%= f.text_field :variable4 %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/static_pages/manager.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/verevkinra/apps/yurta24
```

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty on the second line of this code (app/view/items/new.html.erb):

```
<h1>Items manage</h1>
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :variable1 %>
   <%= f.text_field :variable2 %>
   <%= f.text_field :variable3 %>
   <%= f.text_field :variable4 %>
   <%= f.text_field :value1 %>
   <%= f.text_field :value2 %>
   <%= f.text_field :value3 %>
   <%= f.text_field :value4 %>
   <%= f.text_field :comment %>

   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My Items_controller.rb is:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

      def new
       @item = Item.new
    end
    def create
       @item = Item.new item_params
       @item.save
    end

    def destroy
         @item = Item.find(params[:id])
         @item.destroy
      end

    private

    def item_params
       params.require(:item).permit(:variable1, :variable2, :variable3, :variable4, :value1, :value2, :value3, :value4, :comment)
    end
end
```

My DB migration file is:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table @item do |t|
      t.string :variable1
      t.string :variable2
      t.string :variable3
      t.string :variable4
      t.string :value1
      t.string :value2
      t.string :value3
      t.string :value4
      t.string :comment

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

My routes.rb has next line:

```
resources :items
```

Thanks

My static_pages_controller.rb is:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new 
  end

  def manager
    @contact_messages = ContactForm.all
    @item = Item.new
  end
end
```

Line `@item = Item.new` I've add right now and there is another error:

```
NoMethodError in StaticPages#manager

Showing /home/verevkinra/apps/yurta24/app/views/items/_new.html.erb where line #8 raised:

undefined method `value2' for #<Item:0xb3ba6504>

Extracted source (around line #8):
   <%= f.text_field :variable4 %>
   <%= f.text_field :value1 %>
   <%= f.text_field :value2 %>
   <%= f.text_field :value3 %>
   <%= f.text_field :value4 %>
   <%= f.text_field :comment %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/static_pages/manager.html.erb
```

app/views/static_pages/manager.html.erb is:

```
<%= render 'contact_forms/new' %>
<%= render 'items/new' %>
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error stacktrace in the question?

Comment: Please post the code of `app/views/static_pages/manager.html.erb` in the question

Comment: @Pavan I've add the code.

Comment: Wait, `create_table @item do |t|` should be `create_table :items do |t|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

You are rendering that ***partial***(`app/views/items/_new.html.erb`) in `app/views/static_pages/manager.html.erb`, so you should be having `@item = Item.new` in `manager` method of `static_pages_controller.rb`

```
#static_pages_controller.rb
def manager
  @item = Item.new
end
```

> undefined method `value2' for Item:0xb3ba6504

<s>That attribute `value2` not find in `items` table. Create a migration with the below command</s>

<s>`rails g migration add_value2_to_items value2:string`</s>

Change `create_table @item do |t|` to `create_table :items do |t|` in the migration file and do `rake db:migrate`

Comment: But now I have it and there is another error. I've update my question with it.

Comment: it's too late, I've done migration :) It looks ok :) It is better to update code?

Comment: @RichPeck Use `<s> </s>` to strike a line :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, you answer helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Your variable `@item` is not populated.

---

I started writing this before you updated, so I'll add the fixes afterwards...

```
app/views/static_pages/manager.html.erb
```

This tells us the error is likely originating from the `manager` action of `StaticPagesController`. Specifically, you'll probably not have `@item` defined there...

So the first thing is to do the following:

```
#app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
   def manager
      @item = Item.new
   end
end
```

--

With your updated code, here's the new problem:

> undefined method `value2' for #

This means you've not got an attribute called `value2` for your `Item` model.

There are several solutions to this; the underlying fix is to get your `attribute` names sorted out properly.

```
t.string :variable1
t.string :variable2
t.string :variable3
t.string :variable4
t.string :value1
t.string :value2
t.string :value3
t.string :value4
t.string :comment
```

Since when did a model have `variable1`, `variable2`, etc?

Ruby / Rails has the unrivalled capacity to call *objects*, which means you'll be able to do the following: `@item.name` etc... and yet you call `@item.variable1`?

These *may* be what you need, but if you're adding them for the sake of it, you need to rethink the construct of your model.

That is, you need to rename your attributes to be more fitting to what data they're going to hold. You'll improve as a developer & code architect as a result.

---

**Partial**

Finally, don't call `@instance_variables` in partials.

Partials are meant to be called throughout your application, and should not be bound to specific data-structures. Rails can pass *local* variables to your partials using the following code:

```
<%= render 'items/new', locals: {item: @item} %>

#app/views/items/_new.html.erb
<%= form_for item do |f| %>
```

Comment: thank you a lot! The answer is too detailed and necessary. I'll change my code :)

Answer (score 0):

You should show StaticPages controller and especially method `manager`, which is missing here. Also, try to minimize the problem so that you still get the error.

Also having the stacktrace would help.

Update: at least your migration has an error. It's `create_table :items`, or `create_table "items"`.